# i want to change the background of input field based off the type of data how can this effect be achieved?

Tags: javascript, html

so guys i want to check the value of an input field actively( meaning with every character entered into field or as they are typed)

AND

change the background-color of that field based on what DATA TYPE was entered,
string data or numerical data

how would i /can i achieve that effect with javascript?

for example say i have this code

```js
 var x = document.getElementById( "inpt1" ).value ;

    (function Validateforminput(){
    if (x == numericaldata) \* <--- i dont know how to tell java to check for numerical data so i wrote numericaldata */
    {
    document.getElementById( "inpt1" ).style.backgroundColor = "red" ;
    }
    else { document.getElementById( "inpt1" ).style.backgroundColor = "green" ; \\ im guessing if it is not numerical data then it must be a string
    }
    };()
```

```html
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="inpt1" placeholder="firstName"
    style="width:100px;height:100px;">
```

As you can see my goal is to have an input field that represents first name. And in that field i want to Validate the characters typed by using a self evoking function(or loop whichever works)that changes the background color of field. if it is a string/character the background turns green if it's a number the field will turn red

Comment: you want to check if the next digit is number or not and then change color? or if the whole text is string or number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var inputField = document.getElementById('inpt1');
var input = inputField.value;
var datatype = typeof input;

if (datatype === "string") {
    inputField.style.backgroundColor = "green";
} else if (datatype === "Number" && input.isFinite()) {
    inputField.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
    alert('Invalid datatype');
}
```

I think this would work.

EDIT:

Just realised anything you will take from HTML will always be a string unless the type of your input tag is *value*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
isNaN(Number(x))
```

This will return true for any string that doesn't parse correctly as a number, false for anything that JavaScript considers a valid number.

If you want stricter parsing rules (integer only, no exponential notation, etc.) or looser rules (allow commas separting thousands, for example), you'll have to use a regex or write another more complicated test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the digit upon typing so you can do this with jQuery:

```
$(function(){

  $('input').keyup(function(){
    var digit = $(this).val().slice(-1);

    if(! isNaN(digit)){
       $(this).css('background', 'red');
    } else {
       $(this).css('background', 'green');
    }
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aq1vrnt7/14/